# Mathematical calculation of engine fuel injectors

Tags: python, python-3.x, calculator

There is a code that performs calculations of parts of fuel injectors. There are two classes in which the basic calculations take place, they are called `LiquidJetInjector` and `GasJetInjector`, respectively.

The `Reynolds` class stores constants for calculations.

The `SimilarCalculations` class is a class in which the calculations required in both `LiquidJetInjector` and `GasJetInjector` take place.

In order for the code to work correctly, first we need to pass the basic values to the `SimilarCalculations` class, and then to the class whose calculations we are interested in.

```
import math
from enum import Enum


class SimilarCalculations:
    def __init__(self, diameter: float, length: float, mass_flow_rate: float, viscosity: float, density: float):
        self.diameter = diameter
        self.length = length
        self.mass_flow_rate = mass_flow_rate
        self.viscosity = viscosity
        self.density = density

    def injector_nozzle_area(self) -> float:
        return (math.pi * self.diameter ** 2) / 4

    def reynolds_number(self) -> float:
        return (4 * self.mass_flow_rate) / (math.pi * self.diameter * self.viscosity)

    def average_speed(self) -> float:
        return self.mass_flow_rate / (self.density * self.injector_nozzle_area())

    def relative_length_injector(self) -> float:
        return self.length / self.diameter


class Reynolds(Enum):
    LAMINAR = 2000
    TURBULENT = 10000


class LiquidJetInjector:
    def __init__(self, density_comb: float, sigma_fuel: float):
        self.calculations = SimilarCalculations(diameter, length, mass_flow_rate, viscosity, density)

        self.density_comb = density_comb
        self.sigma_fuel = sigma_fuel

        self.reynolds_number = self.calculations.reynolds_number()
        self.injector_nozzle_area = self.calculations.injector_nozzle_area()
        self.average_speed = self.calculations.average_speed()

    def linear_hydraulic_resistance(self) -> float:
        if self.reynolds_number < Reynolds.LAMINAR.value:
            return 64 / self.reynolds_number

        elif Reynolds.LAMINAR.value <= self.reynolds_number <= Reynolds.TURBULENT.value:
            return 0.3164 * self.reynolds_number ** (-0.25)

        else:
            return 0.031

    def injector_losses_inlet(self) -> float:
        if self.reynolds_number < Reynolds.LAMINAR.value:
            return 2.2 - 0.726 * math.exp(-74.5 * ((viscosity * length) / mass_flow_rate))
        else:
            return 1 + 2.65 * self.linear_hydraulic_resistance()

    def injector_flow_coefficient(self) -> float:
        return 1 / (math.sqrt(self.injector_losses_inlet() + self.linear_hydraulic_resistance() *
                              (length / diameter)))

    def pressure_drop_injector(self) -> float:
        return mass_flow_rate ** 2 / (2 * density * self.injector_flow_coefficient() ** 2 * self.injector_nozzle_area **
                                      2)

    def weber_criterion(self) -> float:
        return (self.density_comb * self.average_speed ** 2 * diameter) / self.sigma_fuel

    def media_diameter_spray_droplets(self) -> float:
        return diameter * round(math.pow((27 * math.pi) / 4, 1 / 3.)) * self.weber_criterion() ** (-0.333)


class GasJetInjector:
    def __init__(self, combustion_pressure: float, pressure_drop_internal_circuit: float, gas_constant_gen_gas: float,
                 temperature_gen_gas: float, entropy_expansion_ratio: float):
        self.calculations = SimilarCalculations(diameter, length, mass_flow_rate, viscosity, density)

        self.reynolds_number = self.calculations.reynolds_number()
        self.injector_nozzle_area = self.calculations.injector_nozzle_area()
        self.average_speed = self.calculations.average_speed()

        self.combustion_pressure = combustion_pressure
        self.pressure_drop_internal_circuit = pressure_drop_internal_circuit
        self.gas_constant_gen_gas = gas_constant_gen_gas
        self.temperature_gen_gas = temperature_gen_gas
        self.entropy_expansion_ratio = entropy_expansion_ratio

    def calculate_injector_pressure(self) -> float:
        return self.combustion_pressure + self.pressure_drop_internal_circuit

    def density_gen_gas(self) -> float:
        return self.calculate_injector_pressure() / (self.gas_constant_gen_gas * self.temperature_gen_gas)

    def injector_flow_coefficient(self) -> float:
        return (math.sqrt(1.23 ** 2 + (232 * length) / (self.reynolds_number * diameter))) / \
               ((116 * length) / (self.reynolds_number * diameter))

    def injector_nozzle_area_outlet(self) -> float:
        return mass_flow_rate / (self.injector_flow_coefficient() * density * (
                self.combustion_pressure / self.calculate_injector_pressure()) ** (1 / self.entropy_expansion_ratio) *
                                 math.sqrt(2 * (self.entropy_expansion_ratio / (self.entropy_expansion_ratio - 1)) *
                                           self.gas_constant_gen_gas * self.temperature_gen_gas * (1 - (
                                            self.combustion_pressure / self.calculate_injector_pressure()) ** (
                                            (self.entropy_expansion_ratio - 1) / self.entropy_expansion_ratio))))

    def checking_diameter_injector(self) -> float:
        return math.sqrt((4 * self.injector_nozzle_area_outlet()) / math.pi)
```

To test the values at the end of the code, I used this construction (it is temporary and will not be in the final version, but I will attach it to understand the work)

```
#
diameter = 0.0005
length = 0.002
mass_flow_rate = 0.00712
viscosity = 0.00116
density = 1315
#
density_comb = 0.1
sigma_fuel = 0.5
#
combustion_pressure = 14.58 * 10**6
pressure_drop_internal_circuit = 10**6
gas_constant_gen_gas = 260.5
temperature_gen_gas = 777.4
entropy_expansion_ratio = 1.23
#
calc = SimilarCalculations(diameter, length, mass_flow_rate, viscosity, density)
calc_2 = LiquidJetInjector(density_comb, sigma_fuel)
calc_3 = GasJetInjector(combustion_pressure, pressure_drop_internal_circuit, gas_constant_gen_gas, temperature_gen_gas, entropy_expansion_ratio)
#
print(calc_3.injector_nozzle_area_outlet())
print(calc_2.injector_flow_coefficient())
print(calc.injector_nozzle_area())
```

For a more accurate understanding of the formulas and parameters written in the code, I attach a link to the source of the manual according to which the code was written. The required pages are `38-44`.

[The manual for the calculation of liquid propellant injectors](http://repo.ssau.ru/bitstream/Uchebnye-izdaniya/Raschet-i-proektirovanie-smeseobrazovaniya-v-kamere-ZhRD-Elektronnyi-resurs-ucheb-posobie-78330/1/%D0%95%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B2%20%D0%92.%D0%A1%20%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%20%D0%96%D0%A0%D0%94%202008.pdf?ysclid=lsou9sw8vx671497901)

Comment: Have you thought about having the ```SimilarCalculations``` class as a base class and inheriting it in the specific injector classes? This seems like a good case for inheritance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SimilarCalculations` is not a very good name. If we interpret it to be a superclass of your other two classes, it can simply be `Injector`. A superclass would be a simple and remove the need for a `calculations` member.

In your equations there's a lot of redundant parens, and not enough linebreaks. I'll demonstrate an alternative format that I find a little easier to understand.

Nearly all of your methods are simple and non-mutating. That's good! It means that they can be made `@property`.

Because your code is already non-mutating, you can tighten the class definition to a frozen `dataclass`.

You use `math.pow` in a place where the `**` operator is simpler. Also, you write `** (-0.333)` in the same line as raising to the power of `1 / 3.`; the latter will be more accurate.

In your demo, you describe it as temporary - but it should be permanent! Convert it to unit tests.

### Suggested

```py
import math
from dataclasses import dataclass
from enum import Enum


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Injector:
    density: float
    diameter: float
    length: float
    mass_flow_rate: float
    viscosity: float

    @property
    def injector_nozzle_area(self) -> float:
        return math.pi * self.diameter**2 / 4

    @property
    def reynolds_number(self) -> float:
        return 4 * self.mass_flow_rate / (math.pi * self.diameter * self.viscosity)

    @property
    def average_speed(self) -> float:
        return self.mass_flow_rate / (self.density * self.injector_nozzle_area)

    @property
    def relative_length_injector(self) -> float:
        return self.length / self.diameter


class Reynolds(Enum):
    LAMINAR = 2000
    TURBULENT = 10000


@dataclass(frozen=True, slots=True)
class LiquidJetInjector(Injector):
    density_comb: float
    sigma_fuel: float

    @property
    def linear_hydraulic_resistance(self) -> float:
        if self.reynolds_number < Reynolds.LAMINAR.value:
            return 64 / self.reynolds_number
        elif Reynolds.LAMINAR.value <= self.reynolds_number <= Reynolds.TURBULENT.value:
            return 0.3164 * self.reynolds_number**-0.25
        return 0.031

    @property
    def injector_losses_inlet(self) -> float:
        if self.reynolds_number < Reynolds.LAMINAR.value:
            return 2.2 - 0.726*math.exp(-74.5 * self.viscosity * self.length / self.mass_flow_rate)
        return 1 + 2.65 * self.linear_hydraulic_resistance

    @property
    def injector_flow_coefficient(self) -> float:
        return 1 / math.sqrt(
            self.injector_losses_inlet
            + self.linear_hydraulic_resistance * self.length / self.diameter
        )

    @property
    def pressure_drop_injector(self) -> float:
        return self.mass_flow_rate**2 / (
            2 * self.density * self.injector_flow_coefficient**2 *
            self.injector_nozzle_area**2
        )

    @property
    def weber_criterion(self) -> float:
        return self.density_comb * self.average_speed**2 * self.diameter / self.sigma_fuel

    @property
    def media_diameter_spray_droplets(self) -> float:
        return self.diameter * round(
            (27 * math.pi / 4)**(1/3)
        ) * self.weber_criterion**(-1/3)


@dataclass(frozen=True, slots=True)
class GasJetInjector(Injector):
    combustion_pressure: float
    pressure_drop_internal_circuit: float
    gas_constant_gen_gas: float
    temperature_gen_gas: float
    entropy_expansion_ratio: float

    @property
    def injector_pressure(self) -> float:
        return self.combustion_pressure + self.pressure_drop_internal_circuit

    @property
    def density_gen_gas(self) -> float:
        return self.injector_pressure / (self.gas_constant_gen_gas * self.temperature_gen_gas)

    @property
    def injector_flow_coefficient(self) -> float:
        return math.sqrt(
            1.23**2 + 232*self.length / (self.reynolds_number * self.diameter)
        ) / (116 * self.length) * self.reynolds_number * self.diameter

    @property
    def injector_nozzle_area_outlet(self) -> float:
        return self.mass_flow_rate / (
            self.injector_flow_coefficient * self.density * (
                self.combustion_pressure / self.injector_pressure
            ) ** (1 / self.entropy_expansion_ratio) *
            math.sqrt(
                2 * self.entropy_expansion_ratio / (self.entropy_expansion_ratio - 1) *
                self.gas_constant_gen_gas * self.temperature_gen_gas * (
                    1 - (
                        self.combustion_pressure / self.injector_pressure
                    ) ** (
                        (self.entropy_expansion_ratio - 1) / self.entropy_expansion_ratio
                    )
                )
            )
        )

    @property
    def checking_diameter_injector(self) -> float:
        return math.sqrt(4 * self.injector_nozzle_area_outlet / math.pi)


def test() -> None:
    common = {
        'diameter': 0.0005,
        'length': 0.002,
        'mass_flow_rate': 0.00712,
        'viscosity': 0.00116,
        'density': 1315,
    }

    liquid = LiquidJetInjector(
        **common, density_comb=0.1, sigma_fuel=0.5,
    )
    gas = GasJetInjector(
        **common,
        combustion_pressure=14.58e6,
        pressure_drop_internal_circuit=1e6,
        gas_constant_gen_gas=260.5,
        temperature_gen_gas=777.4,
        entropy_expansion_ratio=1.23,
    )

    assert math.isclose(gas.injector_nozzle_area_outlet, 8.279311695661635e-10)
    assert math.isclose(gas.injector_nozzle_area, 1.9634954084936206e-07)
    assert math.isclose(liquid.injector_flow_coefficient, 0.9105406506118756)
    assert math.isclose(liquid.injector_nozzle_area, 1.9634954084936206e-07)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Answer (score 4):

## naming

Carefully choose identifiers.
These are terrific names:

- GasJetInjector
- LiquidJetInjector

So is `Reynolds`.
But a "similar" prefix is not a good choice.
It describes a relationship between others, rather than what it is.
Minimally prefer a "common" prefix.
And making each class name a noun is good,
but this is not exactly a "calculations" object.

From just reading your names, a `JetInjector` class seems
most appropriate. Or perhaps `Injector`.

## two things in one

The `__init__` ctor accepts five parameters.
Given that there's no """docstring""" I assume we have
[MKS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MKS_units) SI units.
The first two are perfect: they describe an `Injector`.
The next three describe dynamic fluid conditions,
and maybe belong in a `Fluid` or `Flow`
[@dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html).
Or perhaps they are the nominal operating point this injector
was designed for?
Except that you didn't `# comment` on that,
nor cite a reference where I could tell what is usual in this situation.
They're certainly not "do not exceed" parameters,
since they don't start with a `max_` prefix.

Or maybe this truly is a single thing: an `Experiment` object.

## property descriptors

`injector_nozzle_area()` is lovely -- area is a property of the
injector, fully described by the diameter.
Consider making it a dynamically computed attribute of the object:

```
    @property
    def nozzle_area(self) -> float:
        return (math.pi * self.diameter ** 2) / 4
...
print(my_injector.nozzle_area)
```

Similarly for `relative_length`.

I found that the "injector_" prefix was perhaps a bit redundant.
Similarly for other "_injector" suffixes and prefixes.

In contrast, average speed and the dimensionless Reynolds number
come from the combination of a physical injector and
a dynamic flow.
Maybe that combination is an `OperatingPoint` class
which holds both?
Or maybe just leave them as functions which accept both as args.

## piecewise continuous

The `linear_hydraulic_resistance()` function is a nice piecewise model.
It is not at all clear that it is continuous,
and that seems worth commenting on in the source code.
Or cite a reference, and let *that* author sweat the details.
That way we'd also learn what the cryptic `density_comb` denotes.

EDIT: Section 2.1.11 explains it is the density of combustion products.

I'm assuming ATM that `sigma_fuel` is surface tension
in N/m, but it would be nice to either explicitly spell that out
or cite a reference that does.

## lint

Layout of this source code is idiosyncratic,
changing from function to function.
Recommend you run
[$ black *.py](https://pypi.org/project/black)
against it before sharing it with colleagues.

## automated tests

There aren't any.
The `print()`'s are nice enough,
but they are not self evaluating.
I could not run them, eyeball them, and
proclaim, "Oh, yes, those figures are definitely right!".

It's not hard, write a
[test suite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase).

## correctness

Absent citations, or the URL of a description for the
laboratory setup where you observed and recorded fluid properties,
it isn't feasible for me to tell whether this code
correctly computes desired figures or not.
Cite your references, already.

---

This code achieves some of its design goals.

In its current form I would not be willing to
delegate or accept maintenance tasks on it.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable comments! I added a link to the tutorial on which the code was written, I hope this will clarify the difficult points with its understanding